# Dropdown Box and then MSG Prompt

Tags: excel, vba

:

I have 5 values in a drop box which covers cells `C7:AD18`, the idea is that when a user selects one of the users select for instance Value1 a Msgbox will popup `"Thanks for Selecting Value1"`

The issue I have encountered is that the only way I can do it is by setting up the programming for EACH cell:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C7")) Is Nothing Then
   Select Case Range("C7")
      Case "Value1": Macro1
      Case "Value2": Macro2
      Case "Value3": Macro3
      Case "Value4": Macro4
      Case "Value5": Macro5
   End Select
End IF
End Sub
```

I have then had to add an entry for `C8, C9, C10` Etc, I have tried to use a range of `"C7:AD18"` but I can't get it to work at all, it keeps coming back to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the following, which tests whether `Target` falls within that range using `Intersect`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge <> 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C7:AD18")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target.Value
            Case "Value1": Macro1
            Case "Value2": Macro2
            Case "Value3": Macro3
            Case "Value4": Macro4
            Case "Value5": Macro5
       End Select
    End If
End Sub
```